# insert mysql record with table format in a string then echo in a html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok, I have this code.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$hi1='<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />';  
$hi2= $row['title'];
$hi3= $row['description'];
$hi4= $row['link'];
}
```

Now, Im in a process of making those records above to display in a table view and that 4 row should be on one td and so the rest.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to know how to output the variables in html elements?

Comment: Ok, what i want is to make it list in a table, now i did display it on the table, thanks to you but the problem is, all items display horizontally so its kinda mess and i want to divide it so that all items are organize and i can control all items in the table, so I want 3 td in 1 tr, i mean 3 items in 1 TR. so please do you have an idea on how to make it?

Comment: heres the query

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

as you can see my point, i want to display all records.

i did put all row on one string so that I could display it in one, however it only display 1 record, I need to display each records in separate div or td, I think its easier if I make it on div, i just float the items/records dev to the left and then wrap all dev in a dev which will be the container of all dev, but yet i dont know how to do it. If Im going to make it with the table, then it I want to make  only 3tds in 1 tr so that I could organize the table

Comment: Ok. I tried this

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $ss = "<div>".'<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />';  
  $ss. $row['title'];
  $ss. $row['description'];
  $ss. $row['link']."<div>";
  }

then i echo the $ss "<? echo $ss; ?> on the html. It display only 1 record yet it display only the picture, however i tried the method to manually echo those rows and it works just fine. how does it happen to display only one record and only the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$i=0;

echo"<table> <tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if($i %4 ==0)
  {
     echo"</tr> <tr>";
  }
    echo'<td><img src="'.$row['name'].'" /> </td>';  
    echo"<td>$row[title]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[description]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[link] </td>";
   $i++;  
}

echo"</tr></table>";
```

---Update

```
   $str ='';
   $str="<table> <tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if($i %4 ==0)
  {
     str.="</tr> <tr>";
  }
    str.="<td><img src='$row['name']' /> </td>";  
    str.="<td>$row[title]</td>";
    str.="<td>$row[description]</td>";
    str.="<td>$row[link] </td>";
   $i++;  
}

str.="</tr></table>";

echo"$str";
```

Comment: I want to put it on 1 string so that I could echo it on the html. can you give me idea on how to do it? and my bad,

this one
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='1'");

should be, this one
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

Comment: In above code replace all `echo` with string variable like `$tableContent=<table><tr>` then instead of all other echo use `$tableContent.=</tr><tr>` [.- is concatentation operator]

Comment: Is there anyway I could put it all in one string so that I could echo it once?

Comment: As i said earlier, replace all the echos in my answer with `$tableContent.=`

Comment: ah ok i see .. let me give it a shot.

Comment: Ok it works. now I want to display only 3 td's in 1tr and just what it should be for the rest. How should I do that? do you have an idea please?

Comment: Y do you want to display only 3 td in one tr, you can remove not required field.

Comment: So that I could control and organize the items.

Comment: or make it with div element, so all i need to do is make it float to the left and specified the width of the container of those item div, of course it will collapse then it should go 3 by 3 div. so do you know how to make it please? instead of table then lets make it on div elements and i think it should be wee' bit easier. I mean one record (name, title, description, link) in one div and loop that div. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I tried this $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $ss = "<div>".'<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />'; $ss. $row['title']; $ss. $row['description']; $ss. $row['link']."<div>"; } then i echo the $ss "<? echo $ss; ?> on the html. It display only 1 record yet it display only the picture, however i tried the method to manually echo those rows and it works just fine. how does it happen to display only one record and only the picture?

Comment: I have updated the answer check it

Answer (score 0):

You just print or echo your php code inside of whichever cell you want. Like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php print $hi1; ?></td>
<td><?php print $hi2; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or you could echo HTML inside of PHP code, like this:

```
<?php

print "<table><tr>";
print "<td>" . $hi1 . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $hi2 . "</td>";
print "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Edit:

I think I get you now. Do this:

```
$table = "<table><tr>";
$table .= "<td>" . $hi1 . "</td>"; 
$table .= "<td>" . $hi2 . "</td>"; 
$table .= "<td>" . $hi3 . "</td>"; 
$table .= "<td>" . $hi4 . "</td>"; 
$table .= "</tr></table>"; 
//now $table is one long string

echo $table;
```

Comment: No, I dont want to echo it one by one, actually my idea is to put it in one string then echo on the table, but i dont know how to do it, do you have idea on how to do it?

Comment: Ok, it works like charm, ahm I would like to ask, How to do make it 3td's in 1tr, so that I could control and organize the list of the items? Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I tried this $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $ss = "<div>".'<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />'; $ss. $row['title']; $ss. $row['description']; $ss. $row['link']."<div>"; } then i echo the $ss "<? echo $ss; ?> on the html. It display only 1 record yet it display only the picture, however i tried the method to manually echo those rows and it works just fine. how does it happen to display only one record and only the picture?

Comment: I'd sure appreciate a vote up or marked answer!

Comment: There's a checkmark next to my answer. Check it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='1'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $hi1='<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />';  
        $hi2= $row['title'];
        $hi3= $row['description'];
        $hi4= $row['link'];
    }
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $hi; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $h2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $h3; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $h4; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Single Echo - Multiple rows in one table.

```
<?php
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='1'");
    //set value of table_data to begin a table
    $table_data = '<table>'
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //add each record as a table row
        $table_data .='<tr><td><img src="'.$row['name'].'" /></td>';  
        $table_data .='<td>'.$row["title"].'</td>';
        $table_data .='<td>'.$row["description"].'</td>';
        $table_data .='<td>'.$row["link"].'</td></tr>';
    }
    //add end table tag
    $table_data .= '</table>';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $table_data; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, this is might what im looking for, it works, but what i want to do is to loop all records in my database table name "items" and put all row in one string and then echo those row in one place. do you have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Ok. I tried this $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $ss = "<div>".'<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />'; $ss. $row['title']; $ss. $row['description']; $ss. $row['link']."<div>"; } then i echo the $ss "<? echo $ss; ?> on the html. It display only 1 record yet it display only the picture, however i tried the method to manually echo those rows and it works just fine. how does it happen to display only one record and only the picture?

Comment: if you use echo outside of the while loop, it will only echo the last item. If you use it at the end of your while loop, it will echo each row as it processes it. In other words the variable $ss is reset each time a new record is processed.

Comment: If you are accepting this as a solution please click the check box on the left. thanks.